# How to select following data points in high charts

Tags: selenium, highcharts

How to write xpath to select point before orange mark

[image: enter link description here]

My xpath to get orange plot is

```
//*[contains(@class,"highcharts-line-series")]/*[@fill="#FF9700"]
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that by "point before orange mark" you mean a data point that occurs before a month marked with an orange dot. If that's what you mean, then you can use this XPath

```
//path[@fill='#FF9700']/preceding-sibling::path[1]
```

You haven't posted the rest of the HTML so you may need to add some context to that using something like what you already posted, e.g.

```
//*[contains(@class,"highcharts-line-series")]/path[@fill='#FF9700']/preceding-sibling::path[1]
```